# Best way to handle mail request and messages

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, email

I am building an MVC app and in this appllication there are actions that implies some things. So we wish to warn our customers / users using mailing system. I'm building both a local application and a web store, so I'll need to send a lot of mails sometimes.

I am currently using `MvcMailer` why does nicely its job, but my main concern is that since it occurs during a normal method call (ex: result of an operation, then:

```
        MvcMailMessage msg = mailer.NewOrder(emailTo);

        msg.Send();
```

And the message goes, it takes a while. And since this kind of operation might be called quite a few times, it will overall slow down the whole process, which I do not wish.

So my question is: how should I handle mail processing? Is there an asynchroneous thing I may use that will do the job? Do I store them in a database table and send them sometimes? I've heard about `Task` in windows .Net, but I've never used any, is that an option?

I'm looking for suggestions, so feel free to share your opinion! Thank you!

Comment: Which version of ASP.NET are you using?

Comment: Latest, MVC 5.0 mainly.

Comment: Improving working code is offtopic for SO. Try programmers / code review. I would look into a message queue that a dedicated service will process.

Comment: I'd love to delve into something like that. Do you have any examples or places where I could check out how this could work?

Comment: The easiest to set up would be, I guess, a database-backed queue and a Windows Service for the sending. You can also look into MSMQ, Scheduled Tasks or third-party solutions.

Comment: Would you post your comment as an answer please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`SmtpClient.SendMailAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193922(v=vs.110).aspx)  using the [`async-await`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx)  keywords

```
public async Task SendSmtpMailAsync()
{
    SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
    MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage("FromAddress", "ToAddress", "Subject", "Body");

    await smtpClient.SendMailAsync(mailMessage);
    // Possibly do more stuff here.
}
```

When you `await` on an asynchronous method, control yields back to the caller. What that means is that the ASP.NET can process messages in the meantime using the thread that returned to the ASP
NET ThreadPool from that same method. When the method finishes, it will return back to the awaited line and continue execution.

Note that using this `async` alone wont return the request to the caller, it will simply let you process more requests in the meanwhile. What you can do is use this method in correlation with a producer-consumer style collection, like [`BlockingCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312(v=vs.110).aspx), add your messages to it and return the response to you caller. In the background, use `SendMailAsync` to execute these requests.

Comment: This will not take any time off of the request processing time, it just means your system can potentially handle a greater load by not holding up idle threads.

Comment: @CodeCaster It wont, but it will let him execute more requests in the meantime. I wouldn't advise using fire and forget methods in ASP.NET

Comment: _"my main concern is that since it occurs during a normal method call (ex: result of an operation) [...] , it takes a while"_ - OP wants the users of his application not having to wait for the sending.

Comment: @CodeCaster I see what you mean. I edited my post to elaborate more of how he can achieve his goal using the asynchronous `SendMail`